# TensorFlow - 3D tensor that gathers every Nth tensor from 2D tensor and strides 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, slice, reshape

Suppose I have a `2D-Tensor` `T` in `[M, 1]` e.g.

```
T = tf.expand_dims([A1,
     B1,
     C1,
     A2,
     B2,
     C2], 1)
```

and I want to reshape it like so:

```
T_reshp = [[[A1], [A2]]
           [[B1], [B2]]
           [[C1], [C2]]]
```

I know `M` and `N` (the number of tensors in each group) in advance. Further, let `t_reshp.shape[0] = M/N = P` in the I have tried using `tf.reshape`

```
T_reshp = tf.reshape(T, [P, N, 1])
```

However, I end up with:

```
T_reshp = [[[A1], [B1]]
           [[C1], [A2]]
           [[B2], [C2]]]
```

Can I do this using some slicing or reshape operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reshape it to dimension `[N,P,1]` first then `transpose` the first and second axis:

```
tf.transpose(tf.reshape(T, [N, P, 1]), [1,0,2])
#                           ^^^^ switch the two dimensions here and then transpose
```

---

*Example*:

```
T = tf.expand_dims([1,2,3,4,5,6], 1)
sess = tf.Session()
T1 = tf.transpose(tf.reshape(T, [2,3,1]), [1,0,2])

sess.run(T1)
#array([[[1],
#        [4]],

#       [[2],
#        [5]],

#       [[3],
#        [6]]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Elegant solution!